# mangoose trying to connect wrong ip and showing err connection refused during dockerization

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, docker-compose

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5' # specify docker-compose version

# Define the services/ containers to be run
services:
   angular: # name of the first service
      build: frontend # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
      ports:
       - "80:80" # specify port mapping

    express: # name of the second service
      build: backend # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
      restart: always
      ports:
      - "100:3000" #specify ports mapping
      links:
      - mongo # link this service to the database service

     mongo: # name of the third service
      image: mongo # specify image to build container from
      container_name: mongo
      ports:
      - "27017:27017" # specify port forwarding
```

when i issue `docker-compose up express`
in server its showing error in this line

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongo:27017/mydb', {useNewUrlParser: true})
```

error is

```
express_1  | { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:27017]
express_1  |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
express_1  |     at Pool.emit (events.js:198:13)
express_1  |     at createConnection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:561:14)
express_1  |     at connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:994:11)
express_1  |     at makeConnection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:31:7)
express_1  |     at Socket.err (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:294:7)
express_1  |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
express_1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
express_1  |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
express_1  |     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
express_1  |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
express_1  |   name: 'MongoNetworkError',
express_1  |   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

why its trying to connect 172.18.0.2:27017 instead of localhost:27017 or docker(192.168.99.100:27017)

thanks in advance scratching my head from last 2 days

Comment: when you do 'docker inspect <express container> | grep IPAddress' what subnet is this container on?

Comment: its coming 172.17.0.2 but my mongo host is running on 192.169.99.100 :27017

Comment: Can you please explain the different subnets?

Comment: running in windows home virtual box                                                                        
 for mongo  "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPAddress": "172.21.0.2",                                                                                        
for express   "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPAddress": "172.21.0.3"

Comment: yesterday i run code it used 172.18.0.2 today i ran again it used different  subnet 172.21.0.2

Comment: https://dev.to/hugodias/wait-for-mongodb-to-start-on-docker-3h8b                                 i used even this it havent worked

Comment: Difficult to reproduce... now that you can verify both containers are on the same subnet, does the database 'mydb' exist? and can you curl '172.21.0.2:27017' from inside of the express container?